Can I set HTTP headers on Google crawler user agent?
I have a website with public limited access, via maximum number of requests per IP per day. Though I don't want to block Google crawler. Just checking for the Google user agent default headers is not a solution, because it would be trivial to emulate and hence bypass the site's limitations.
Hence, can I set HTTP headers on Google user agent with Google Search Console, to embed a key therein?

As far as I know, key embedding is not supported. As an alternative, if you are worried of people faking Googlebot's User Agent, you could double-check by verifying it comes from Google ASIN/ASN (15169). If you have a WAF like CloudFlare, it's easy to enable such a check. Otherwise, you'd need to check against their IP ranges.

Eventually I developped a NPM Express package to detect if request was coming frm Google, based on known IPs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-is-googlecrawler
